# Converting multidimensional array to tuple while conserving format- python

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I'm trying to the convert a multidimensional array with different formats to a tuple all while conserving the different formats. Here is the code that builds the array

```
nodeData=np.empty((npoints*npoints,4))
ii=0
for i in range (npoints):
    for j in range (npoints):
        nodeData[ii,0]=int(ii+1)
        nodeData[ii,1]=float(X[i,j])
        nodeData[ii,2]=float(Y[i,j])
        nodeData[ii,3]=float(Z[i,j])
        ii+=1
```

which outputs

```
[[  1.          10.           2.           0.        ]
 [  2.           9.23463314   1.84775906   0.        ]
 [  3.           8.58578682   1.41421354   0.        ]
 [  4.           8.15224103   0.76536686   0.        ]
 [  5.           8.           0.           0.        ]
 [  6.          10.           4.           0.        ]
 [  7.           8.14486726   3.94570562   0.        ]
 [  8.           6.43933982   3.56066012   0.        ]
 [  9.           6.05429438   1.8551327    0.        ]
 [ 10.           6.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 11.          10.           6.           0.        ]
 [ 12.           7.07624214   6.00295346   0.        ]
 [ 13.           4.29289317   5.70710671   0.        ]
 [ 14.           3.99704657   2.92375783   0.        ]
 [ 15.           4.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 16.          10.           8.           0.        ]
 [ 17.           6.02814844   8.02067549   0.        ]
 [ 18.           2.14644665   7.85355332   0.        ]
 [ 19.           1.97932457   3.97185155   0.        ]
 [ 20.           2.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 21.          10.          10.           0.        ]
 [ 22.           5.          10.           0.        ]
 [ 23.           0.          10.           0.        ]
 [ 24.           0.           5.           0.        ]
 [ 25.           0.           0.           0.        ]]
```

Now when I try to convert this to a tuple using `nodeData = tuple(map(tuple, nodeData))` I obtain

```
((1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 9.234633143257458, 1.847759058732358, 0.0), (3.0, 8.5857868194580078, 1.4142135381698608, 0.0), (4.0, 8.1522410342120963, 0.76536686381751795, 0.0), (5.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0), (6.0, 10.0, 4.0, 0.0), (7.0, 8.144867260307727, 3.9457056195410947, 0.0), (8.0, 6.439339816570282, 3.5606601238250732, 0.0), (9.0, 6.0542943801670015, 1.8551327030961533, 0.0), (10.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0), (11.0, 10.0, 6.0, 0.0), (12.0, 7.0762421416553485, 6.0029534580819224, 0.0), (13.0, 4.2928931713104248, 5.7071067094802856, 0.0), (14.0, 3.997046571142258, 2.9237578279641867, 0.0), (15.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0), (16.0, 10.0, 8.0, 0.0), (17.0, 6.028148440014629, 8.0206754926510051, 0.0), (18.0, 2.1464466452598572, 7.8535533249378204, 0.0), (19.0, 1.9793245736169094, 3.9718515524632179, 0.0), (20.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0), (21.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0), (22.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0), (23.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0), (24.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0), (25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

It has converted all the values to floats when I'm trying to conserve the first value of each row as an interger as such:

```
((1, 10.0, 2.0, 0.0),
 (2, 9.234633143257458, 1.847759058732358, 0.0), 
(3, 8.5857868194580078, 1.4142135381698608, 0.0), 
(4, 8.1522410342120963, 0.76536686381751795, 0.0), 
(5, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
(6, 10.0, 4.0, 0.0), 
(7, 8.144867260307727, 3.9457056195410947, 0.0), 
(8, 6.439339816570282, 3.5606601238250732, 0.0), 
(9, 6.0542943801670015, 1.8551327030961533, 0.0), 
(10, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
(11, 10.0, 6.0, 0.0), 
(12, 7.0762421416553485, 6.0029534580819224, 0.0), 
(13, 4.2928931713104248, 5.7071067094802856, 0.0), 
(14, 3.997046571142258, 2.9237578279641867, 0.0), 
(15, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
(16, 10.0, 8.0, 0.0), 
(17, 6.028148440014629, 8.0206754926510051, 0.0), 
(18, 2.1464466452598572, 7.8535533249378204, 0.0), 
(19, 1.9793245736169094, 3.9718515524632179, 0.0), 
(20, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
(21, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0), 
(22, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0), 
(23, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0), 
(24, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0), 
(25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Alternatively is there anyway to get the final result without building the array, rather building the tuple directly in the correct format?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They aren't in "different formats", `numpy.ndarray` objects hold *homogenous data*. Your dtype is a floating point type. You could use a structured array. but what is the point of creating this array in the first place?

Comment: i require the tuple for the construction of a output database for abaqus

Answer (score 1):

You can't build a tuple incrementally, because tuples are immutable. But you can build a list and then convert it to a tuple.

```
nodeData = []
ii = 1
for i in range (npoints):
    for j in range (npoints):
        nodeData.append((ii, float(X[i,j]), float(Y[i,j]), float(Z[i,j])))
        ii += 1
nodeData = tuple(nodeData)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you first create the `nodeData` array, you can check the `dtype` and notice that the array is of type `float64` (see print statement below):

```
npoints = 25
nodeData=np.empty((npoints*npoints,4))
print(nodeData.dtype)

'float64'
```

This means that when you're assigning the integer later, it's automatically converted to a float (see print statement below):

```
npoints = 25
nodeData=np.empty((npoints*npoints,4))
ii=0
for i in range (npoints):
    for j in range (npoints):
        nodeData[ii,0]=int(ii+1)
        print(nodeData[ii,0].dtype)

'float64'...
```

As @barmar suggests, you'll have to build a set of tuples in a way that doesn't cast your integer value to float (the way that setting a value in the numpy array will auto-cast to match the array type).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Barmar's answer, you could also use a generator:

```py
def generate():
    for i in range(npoints):
        for j in range(npoints):
            yield (int(ii+1), float(X[i,j]), float(Y[i,j]), float(Z[i,j]))
            ii += 1

nodeData = tuple(generate())
```